# Python dictionary to a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, python

I have a python aws lambda passing a json.dumps(pythonDict) to the frontend. Then to operate with js and html i need to convert:

```
# from
py_dict = [{'x':"hi", 'y':1, 'z':2}]

# to
js_obj = [{x:"hi", y:1, z:2}]
```

Any way to do it?
Anyone here with the same problem?

Comment: This `js_obj = [{x:"hi", y:1, z:2}]` is not valid Python

Comment: This seems to be a JavaScript question, not a Python one? `json.dumps` is correct to return JSON to the front end

Comment: You've already done all you can: you serialized your `dict` to JSON. It's up to the front end to take the JSON value and deserialize it for its own use.

Comment: That's the *purpose* of things like JSON: to provide a language-agnostic encoding of data structures so you can share them between programs written in different languages.

Comment: you posted the same question yesterday, so expect similar results --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69714009/how-to-convert-python-dictionary-to-a-javascript-object

Comment: @gold_cy
they close that question that is why i open a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you're looking for the JavaScript function `JSON.parse` that can parse a String to a JavaScript object. You're probably getting a String from the backend.